# Power management in Solaris 11 using poweradm?

Tags: hard-drive, cpu, power-management, solaris, suspend

In Oracle Solaris 11.1, `pmconfig` had completely vanished, and `poweradm` is available instead. While `pmconfig` was still available, I used to...

- Auto suspend : Let my server suspend from 2 AM through 7 AM using *autoshutdown* option.
- HDD stop : Let my HDDs stop if idle time lasts over 600 seconds using *device-thresholds /dev/dsk/cxtydzsw 600s* option.
- CPU save : Let my CPU work in low-frequency if possible using *cpupm enable poll-mode* and *cpu-threshold 1s* option.

I've read `man poweradm`, it seems that *time-to-full-capacity* and *time-to-minimum-responsiveness* is what you set for CPU saving, but I couldn't find any options for `poweradm` to set power-saving behaviors to Auto suspending and HDD stopping.

Are there any good ideas using `poweradm` to set and let my server work with all power-saving methods?

Answer (score 1):

Autosuspend - is no longer supported. You can get the same effect by using cron(1M) to run the
sys-suspend(1) at 2:00am

CPU save - cpupm enable poll-mode is no longer supported, however CPU power management can
be enabled by setting time-to-full-capacity to a value larger enough to ensure that C-states are being used. You can check this by running powertop and looking at the C-state residency.

If you have a support contract please file a bug concerning the lack of support for power
managing disks, or any ohter features that you require.